# JMeter - Remote Testing on Linux

Tags: jmeter, jmeter-plugins, jmeter-5.0, jmeter-4.0

I am executing JMeter remote testing with 1 master machine (192.168.0.1) and with 7 slave machines with 3 VMs (192.168.0.2 to 192.168.0.4) on a network interface and 4 other VMs (192.168.0.5 to 192.168.0.8) are in a different network interface.

My JMeter script is located at Master machine - 192.168.0.1

I tried to execute my test with the following command

```
./jmeter -n -t /home/lup01/Document/LuP2021/ITonICE_Lasttest_InfluxDebug_09032021.jmx -l /home/lup01/Document/LuP2021/LuP2021_LastTest_001_14-10-2021_7VMs.jtl -R 192.168.100.2,192.168.100.3,192.168.100.4 -Djava.rmi.server.hostname=192.168.100.6,192.168.100.7,192.168.100.8,192.168.100.9
```

However, the test never started. the screen just hung and after 15 minutes i had to stop the test. I did the sample run only with 3 threads.

On course of debugging, i also checked that, when i executed the test with

`./jmeter -n -t /home/lup01/Document/LuP2021/ITonICE_Lasttest_InfluxDebug_09032021.jmx -l /home/lup01/Document/LuP2021/LuP2021_LastTest_001_14-10-2021_7VMs.jtl -R 192.168.100.2,192.168.100.3,192.168.100.4`
the test was running fine with 3 VMs which are on the same interface as the master machine

However, when i executed the 2nd part

`./jmeter -n -t /home/lup01/Dokumente/LuP2021/ITonICE_Lasttest_InfluxDebug_09032021.jmx -l /home/lup01/Dokumente/LuP2021/LuP2021_LastTest_001_14-10-2021_7VMs.jtl -Djava.rmi.server.hostname=192.168.100.6,192.168.100.7,192.168.100.8,192.168.100.9`

the test got executed but the load was generated only on **the master machine** (192.168.0.1). i validated this by printing the host name in the result file.

Can someone please guide me what changes i need to do to get the test running successfully and the load being generated at the slave machines 192.168.100.6 to 192.168.100.9?

Comment: Can you check if you can access the slaves/agents from the master machine? (e.g with ping command). Ensure all clients are in the same subnet. Please check [JMeter Distributed Testing](https://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/jmeter_distributed_testing_step_by_step.html) for details.

Answer (score 0):

1. JMeter Master machine doesn't generate any load, it only reads .jmx script, transfers it to slaves and collects results.
2. It doesn't make sense to run more than 1 JMeter process on 1 machine, it doesn't provide any benefit and just consumes resources, if you have only one machine - run a single JMeter process, just make sure to follow [JMeter Best Practices](https://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/best-practices.html) and [properly tune this JMeter instance for high throughput testing](https://howtojboss.wordpress.com/2012/07/31/concurrent-high-throughput-performance-testing-with-jmeter/)

If this is some form of an experiment and you have to run multiple JMeter processes on a single host and would like to bind different JMeter instances to different network interfaces - you can do it via "Advanced" tab of the [HTTP Request](https://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/component_reference.html#HTTP_Request) sampler (or [HTTP Request Defaults](https://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/component_reference.html#HTTP_Request_Defaults) if you have more than one sampler) like it's described in [Using IP Spoofing to Simulate Requests from Different IP Addresses with JMeter](https://www.blazemeter.com/blog/using-ip-spoofing-simulate-requests-different-ip-addresses-jmeter)

[image]

Comment: this is not an experiment but an actual load test, where i have couple of VMs connected to 2 different **network interfaces** and in the same subnet mask. 
However, when i am trying to run the test with the command ```./jmeter -n -t ITonICE_Lasttest_InfluxDebug_09032021.jmx -l LuP2021_LastTest_001_14-10-2021_7VMs.jtl -Djava.rmi.server.hostname=192.168.100.6,192.168.100.9``` i feel the arg -Djava.rmi.server.hostname is ignored and the test runs only locally. 
Hence, looking for suggestions on how to make the the arg **-Djava.rmi.server.hostname** considered for the command ?